# Spring support for full and partial java ee

Tags: java, spring

I was going through [Spring framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html) and came across below statement:

> Spring enables you to build applications from "plain old Java objects"
>   (POJOs) and to apply enterprise services non-invasively to POJOs. This
>   capability applies to the Java SE programming model and **to full and
>   partial Java EE**.

When it says `Full & Partial Java EE` what does it mean, can someone please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring frameworks provide you a sets different modules for the ease of implementing enterprise application like - Spring DAO support, Spring IoC container, Spring MVC, web service etc. You can independently pick any one from them without hampering your current application.

Comment: Thanks Razib, I would like to know what they mean by Full Java EE and Partial Java EE in that statement, because they look like contradicting to me, may be I am not reading it properly.